# length of time series to estimate $\phi_2$ for an AR(2)

Tags: time-series, self-study, autoregressive

So I have this question that I am kinda stumped on...

I have an AR(2) model with $\phi_1=0.4$ $\phi_2=0.5$, I need to find how long of a time series I would need to estimate $\phi_2$ with 95% confidence that the estimate is no more than $\pm0.15$

normally when I am working with linear regression I would just calculate SSE and divide by n-2 to get the standard error of the model. My problem is that I have no data and am at loss as to what equation I would use to estimate n.

I know how to estimate $\phi_k$ for k=1,2,3... on rstudio but not what the actual equation that is used to generate the results.

---

So perusing my book I found that CI for estimated values of $\phi_k$ is $\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt n }$ so just set $0.15=\frac{2}{\sqrt n}$ and solve for n...yielding $n=178$ ?

$$0.15\gt\frac{2}{\sqrt n }$$ so $n\gt177$

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Comment: Can you work out the standard error of the estimate?

Comment: put my latest attempt down...probably wrong but feel free to comment

Comment: Compare your first inequality (last line in the current post) with what the corresponding part of the question says in words. Paste them one above the other. What quantity should be "no more than" 0.15?

Comment: It looks okay now (apart from some minor details, such as $<$ where it should be $\leq$). The thing was to realize that the interval half-width (which is $2/\sqrt{n}$) is stated to be $\leq 0.15$.

Answer (score 1):

Converting comments and expanding to an answer:

Since the standard error doesn't depend on the variance of the data, if you have the parameter values and a way to work out the standard error from  $n$,  you should be able to at least approximately (/asymptotically) work out the width of a confidence interval as a function of those things.

Since you know a bound on that width you should be able to turn that into a bound on $n$.

Note that your bound is an *inequality*. This gives you an inequality involving $n$. If you correctly manipulate the inequality, you end up with a lower bound on $n$. There's no need to handwave an equality; the whole thing can be done formally with no additional effort (other than being careful about what happens to the direction of the inequality as you manipulate both sides, but you can  avoid having to remember how to deal with that as long as you never do anything that flips that direction).

---

Outside of that it looks like you're headed in the right direction.

Comment: put up my new attempt...appreciate your time looking at it

Comment: @statsGuy It's completely wrong. Go back to the earlier attempt with the equality you had relating to the interval half-width. Write *that* as an inequality (read the question wording carefully)

Comment: edited again to reflect ur comment....still seems like im doing something wrong

Comment: 1. What happened to your original quote about what $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$ represents? You've forgotten what you typed about it. $\:$ 2. Back up a couple of edits (click on "edited n minutes ago" under your post, scroll down to the edit where you put in the bit about $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$ - edit 4 - and click "rollback" to go back to what you had at that point). Don't change that until you understand what you're doing from there. $\:$ 3. Specifically read what $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$ *is* and then read what the question says about the 0.15 (it specifically states an *in*equality, not an equality)